# How to compare strings after calling split in processing?

Tags: string, match, processing

I am comparing strings from a text file, but for some reason they never match. If I do it in ruby it is very easy, but in processing I can not get it to work.
this is the ruby code that works:

```
f=File.open("priceMap_current_new.txt")

f.each do |str| 
    arrstr=str.split(";")
    if arrstr.length==1
        puts arrstr[0].inspect if arrstr[0]=="next\n"
    end
end
```

Now here's the processing version that doesn't work, *actually it doesnt even work without reading from file*:

```
String[] mystr={"number;zero","number;one","number;two","number;three","number;four"};

for(int i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){
  String[] numbers=split(mystr[i],";");
  if(numbers[0]=="number"){
    println("shoooooooooooooooooout");
  }
}
```

Additionally I would like to ask if there's a way to inspect elements like in ruby, its very handy, because if I print pts[0] in processing I get "next" when its actually "next\n"
or also how to check datatypes in processing. Thanks!

Comment: So what happens if you `println(numbers[0])`?  ie does it even _look_ like your split is working ok?  In ruby you're testing if your split gave you a result, but not in the second code (although I agree... it looks like it should!).

Comment: if i println(numbers[0]) it prints "number" five times. `String[] mystr={"number;zero","number;one","number;two","number;three","number;four"};

for(int i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){
  String[] numbers=split(mystr[i],";");
  println(numbers[0]);
  if(numbers[0]=="number"){
    println("shoooooooooooooooooout");
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if (numbers[0].equals("number"))`

From: [Processing doco](http://processing.org/reference/String.html)

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in
>   "if (a.equals(b))", instead of "if (a == b)".

Comment: ahhhhhhh thanks! i was going crazy, i somehow thought it should work cuz i tested the following code beforehand and *strangely* it worked: `String mystr = "compare me";
if(mystr=="compare me"){
  println("good comparison");
}`

Comment: I don't actually know anything about "processing" ;-)  But my guess is that your test worked, because they're both literals, hence actually the same object.  But in your question, you're using two different objects that happen to contain the same data.  That's how it works in Java, for example. Thanks for accepting ;-)

Comment: makes sense, i guess thats the reason :)